# How to call RedirectToAction in asynchronous Task methods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, redirecttoaction, aspnetcore-environment

I am using MVC aspnetcore dotnetcore 6.0

I do an authorization with a LoginController. When it is success i want to redirect the user into HomeController. But RedirectToAction does not work. My code is here:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLoginAsync(LoginRequestModel requestModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                LoginResponseModel loginResponseModel = new LoginResponseModel();
                var res = _wrapperService.Post<LoginRequestModel, LoginResponseModel>(requestModel, "/api/auth/login");
                var tokenRes = GetTokenInfo(res.Result.Data.Token);

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", requestModel.Email);
                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(tokenRes, "Login");
                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // I want to redirect this but it does not work. 
                return Ok(res.Result);
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var errors = new HttpErrorViewModel()
            {
                Errors = new List<string>()
            };
            errors.Errors.Add(e.InnerException.Message);
            return BadRequest(errors);
        }
        
    }
```

My Ajax code here:

```
function LoginWithMail() {
        var inputs = {};
        $("#form-login .input-login").each(function () {
            inputs[$(this)[0].name] = $(this)[0].value;
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Login/UserLogin/",
            data: inputs,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#Email").removeClass("border border-danger");
                $("#Password").removeClass("border border-danger");
                $("#LoginSpinner").show();
                $("#loginResMessages").html("").removeClass();
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $("#LoginSpinner").hide();

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#LoginSpinner").hide();

                $("#loginResMessages").html("");
```

***I repeat. I want to redirect this code when it is success. I tried many solutions i found but not worked too.
Please help.***

Comment: How does the `HomeController` look like? Are you creating REST APIs in your case?

Comment: HomeController is :

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: You might probably need to wrap the return into a Task like this since you're marking the method as `async`.

Comment: You tried what exactly? Cause it seems to me you didn't. How do you send the request? What is the error? Where does the error occur? etc. Can you bother explaining them?

Comment: @Ergis there is no error. There is a login problem. Did you read what i write? I repeat again. I want to use RedirectToAction() method into this code. It is not working.

Comment: @ArmendUkehaxhaj I tried to use task but it did not work too. I found many solutions on the internet but not worked

Comment: You should put in the question that you are using AJAX. This is not a non-trivial detail. The whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page. Ajax calls never redirect.

Comment: You cannot return RedirectToAction from a ajax call and expect it to work. You have to handle it yourself in your js.

Comment: @mxmissile it is not security vulnerability if i handle url in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you send request to login action with ajax? It can be a problem.

If did you send post request with ajax, just handle the response inside ajax method. If it is success, change the window location to home/index with js.

Comment: I don't redirect the url from ajax. And yes i used ajax to post.

Comment: This is a solution but i don't want to use.

Comment: You want to redirect using ajax, but not through window location. I'm curious what other 'solution' is there

Comment: If I pass url to Ajax success result, doesn't it create a security vulnerability?

Comment: I tried more than one solution for this, but i cant find.  The actual security vulnerability is sending user login information with ajax. Do whatever you want in ajax, after that just submit the form to the action. Then you can redirect wherever you want.